# How to use RSA BSafe Crypto-J library on Enterprise ColdFusion 2016

Tags: encryption, coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2016

On the official [Encrypt() doc page](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encrypt.html), it lists a number of RSA BSafe Crypto-J library encryption options for ColdFusion Enterprise, which I'm using. Under the **Usage** heading, it lists `RSA PKCS#1 v1.5 (sign, verify) (SHA-1,SHA-224,SHA-256,SHA-384,SHA-512)`, of which I want to use the `SHA-256`.

I've tried the following as the `algorithm` parameter, some of which I found googling:

- RS256
- SHA-256
- SHA256
- SHA256withRSA
- sha256WithRSAEncryption

The result is always an error, e.g. for the first one above:

> The RS256 algorithm is not supported by the Security Provider you have chosen.

1. How do I check the Security Provider I apparently have chosen? I don't see anything about it in ColdFusion Administrator.
2. What is the correct string, in my case, to pass as the `algorithm` parameter?

Comment: I could be wrong, but ... I've always thought it was a documentation error. AFAIK, there's no way to generate and/or verify *signatures* with the Encrypt() function, only encrypt things ;-). For signatures, you have to create java.security.Signature objects, like https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2941-experimenting-with-rsa-encrypted-signature-generation-and-verification-in-coldfusion.htm

Comment: ... check the docs `Some of these are not used with the encrypt function, but are used with other functions`. When you say "which I want to use the SHA-256" what do you need? [hmac](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-h-im/hmac.html), verify signatures, ...?

Comment: @Ageax I had tried the java.security.Signature java object from Ben's blog as well, but when running it, it says that initSign() is not a function. Try running the following from Ben's solution on tryccf.com and you will receive this error "The initSign method was not found". You can `abort` before the call to initSign() and see that `signer` is no longer an instance of java.security.Signature... `<cfscript>
signer = createObject( "java", "java.security.Signature" )
 .getInstance( javaCast( "string", "SHA256withRSA" ) )
;
WriteDump(signer);
signer.initSign( "privateKey" );
</cfscript>`

Comment: "signer is no longer an instance of java.security.Signature." It is. It inherits from Signature. "method not found" can also mean the code is passing the wrong type of object.  initSign() expects a java.security.PrivateKey object, not a string.

Comment: Did you try it with a real PrivateKey object (not a plain string)?